# Python scrape table from website?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I'd like to scrape every treasury yield rate that is available on treasury.gov website.

https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Pages/TextView.aspx?data=yieldAll

How would I go about taking this information? I'm assuming that I'd have to use BeautifulSoup or Selenium or something like that (preferably BS4). I'd eventually like to put this data in a Pandas DataFrame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way you can grab the data in a table using requests and beautifulsoup

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Pages/TextView.aspx?data=yieldAll'

r = requests.get(url)
html = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find('table', {"class": "t-chart"})
rows = table.find_all('tr')
data = []
for row in rows[1:]:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])

result = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date', '1 Mo', '2 Mo', '3 Mo', '6 Mo', '1 Yr', '2 Yr', '3 Yr', '5 Yr', '7 Yr', '10 Yr', '20 Yr', '30 Yr'])

print(result)
```

Comment: Column `'2 Mo'` is missing. Just add it to the array to avoid the error: `ValueError: 12 columns passed, passed data had 13 columns`. I tried to edit the answer, but it not possible due to StackOverflow "queue is full".

Answer (score 1):

A different method below to download interest rates after changes to CSV downloads for the "all" time period implemented on June 2, 2022. You could use the historical archive option to download historical data and run this code to update the data.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

csv_url = 'https://home.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/daily-treasury-rates.csv/2022/all?field_tdr_date_value=2022&type=daily_treasury_yield_curve&page&_format=csv'

req = requests.get(csv_url, verify=False)
url_content = req.content

csv_file = open('2022_rates.csv', 'wb')
csv_file.write(url_content)
csv_file.close()

rates_2022 = pd.read_csv('2022_rates.csv')

rates_2022
```