# Table scraping and pagination in steps with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to scrape this website using BeautifulSoup package. I have successfully scraped the page, using pointers from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44704099/python-scrape-table-from-website), but am trying to achieve pagination.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
for num in range(0, 800,80):
    url = 'https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/own-disp?action=getissuer&CIK=0000018349&type=&dateb=&owner=include&start='+ str(num)
    r = requests.get(url)
    html = r.text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    table = soup.find('table', id="transaction-report")
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    data = []
    final = []
    for row in rows[1:]:
        cols = row.find_all('td')
        cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
        data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])
    final = final.append(data)

result = pd.DataFrame(final, columns=['A or D', 'Date', 'Reporting Owner', 'Form', 'Transaction Type', 
                                     'Ownership D or I', 'Number of Securities Transacted', 'Number of Securities Owned',
                                     'Line Number', 'Owner CIK', 'Security Name'])

print(result)
```

The pages increase in increments of 80. However, I am unable to put the pages together in the same dataframe. I tried to create a list called `final` to append the `data` from each page, but I am unsuccessful in doing so.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the final list outside the loop and it will work.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 
final = [] 
for num in range(0, 800,80):
    url = 'https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/own-disp?action=getissuer&CIK=0000018349&type=&dateb=&owner=include&start='+ str(num)
    r = requests.get(url)
    html = r.text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    table = soup.find('table', id="transaction-report")
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    data = []
    for row in rows[1:]:
        cols = row.find_all('td')
        cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
        data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])
    final = final.append(data)

result = pd.DataFrame(final, columns=['A or D', 'Date', 'Reporting Owner', 'Form', 'Transaction Type', 
                                     'Ownership D or I', 'Number of Securities Transacted', 'Number of Securities Owned',
                                     'Line Number', 'Owner CIK', 'Security Name'])

print(result)
```